# Cisco 220 Switch fail over

Tags: switch, redundancy

we have a Cisco 220 Switch, how to fail over this switch, in other words how to have another switch that activates when the first dies?

Thanks !!

Comment: If a device connects to a single switch, the device will lose connectivity when that switch dies, no matter what you try.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to have redundancy in switches is with a protocol called **spanning tree protocol**, which the Cisco 220 supports, as do pretty much all professional switches.  STP works by connecting multiple paths through the switches, and working out which links to disable so there aren't any loops in the enabled links.

In this example, suppose when everything is working, the STP detects the loop, and disables link 3.  Frames from Y to Z go to B then A then C.

```
      +-------1----------------------+
      |  +----2-----+  +-----3-!--+  |
      |  |          |  |          |  |
    ==+==+==+==A  ==+==+==+==B  ==+==+==+==C
            |             |             |
            X             Y             Z
```

If A fails, the protocol will reenable link 3, and 
B and C can communicate again.  Host X, connected only to a failed switch, will be isolated.

Spanning tree is not so tricky to use but do read up on it first.  One critical thing to note is that when a switch goes down, it takes quite a few seconds for the network to heal.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_Tree_Protocol

As said in comments, any host which needs to continue working after a switch failure will need **two ethernet interfaces connected to two switches** and use a) some variety of link aggregation ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation)) to get the resilience. b) some variety of dual-homing, ie with two distinct LANS, or c) take part in STP.  To get any sensible resilience, you might well need to make changes to your basic IP network.

Resilience in general can be a tricky topic.   If you need faster resilience, consider routers and review what really has to be resilient.  It's easy to get carried away worrying about which equipment might fail, without really looking at what's probable.  (Personally I worry most about fuses, cables, power supplies, and internet links.)  Also consider carefully which hosts need to continue performing which tasks, as there may well be other methods of doing what you want.  An example would be making whole web servers resilient by load balancing or similar.

Lastly, do consider how long it takes to fix something.  If you have two half-empty switches, side by side, half the hosts in one and half in the other, it will only take 20 seconds to repatch if a switch fails (once someone notices and goes to the patch panel).  Sometimes that's good enough.

Answer (score -3):

I would recommend you HSRP (Hot Standby Router Protocol). But you will need another cisco switch...:

Example configs and additional information can be found here:  https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipapp_fhrp/configuration/12-2sr/fhp-12-2sr-book/fhp-hsrp.pdf

Also, it depends on what devices will be connected to the switch ?

If you could give us more information it will be very helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: HSRP is for routers, not switches.

Comment: @jonathanjo, have you ever heard of layer 3 switch ?

Comment: @gosport bog: HSRP might well a good solution for this kind of redundancy problem, but it operates on routers by maintaining availability of a default gateway on fixed IP and MAC addresses, "Layer 3 switches" are frame-forwarding switches and packet-forwarding routers in the same box, and might well run HSRP. The equipment in the question, Cisco 220, has no such routing function and thus can't run HSRP. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_Standby_Router_Protocol https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/switches/small-business-220-series-smart-plus-switches/products-command-reference-list.html